# I am keep getting message: Unfortunately "some chinese" has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

[image]

I am keep getting this each 10 sec. What is it about? How can I fix this?
This problem is not related to any app I created, it just happens on emulator I work on in eclipse. I thought it's some common 'error'. I may just lunch avd, unlock the screen and wait few sec for this message to comes up.
This is my very first contact with android emulator, so I am not that fluent, didn't know what else to post. I found logcat but it is empty.

Comment: Post some code AND logcat, how can people answer you with only a screenshot (in chinese)?!

Comment: @Mangusto and Houcine: Just because a problem is related to programming (i.e. on-topic for StackOverflow), doesn't mean it has code associated with it. I just had the same problem, and finding this question helped me resolve it.

Comment: I was having the same problem with a brand new installation of the emulator trying to run a brand new Titanium Mobile app. The answer from Huang below fixed the problem. Comments are too short for me to post the exception.

Comment: That translates to "Google Pinyin Input Method". It's what my people use to type Chinese

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These chinese characters say:"Google's PinYin input method",so I guess this problem is related to the input method(PinYin is a way to mark the pronunciation for a character with Latin letters) . It seems that this happens when you are inputting something in the TextView. On the emulator, there is a native Google PinYin input method and perhaps this app has something wrong. Please disable it or create a new emulator.

Actually, how is your app on a real device?

[image]

Comment: Was having the same problem with the emulator and this fixed it!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Actually, I have never run into such a problem, and I "guess" what happened just because I am a Chinese and thus understand what the dialog says.

Answer (score 3):

There is probably a Japanese keyboard trying to run, turn it off from Settings->Language & Keyboard

Answer (score 3):

Being a couple of days into Android development, I encountered the same issue. It only began, however, after I was playing around with the system settings of the emulator. I could have *sworn* that I didn't change a thing in the languages and settings menu. But, since I did inspect it and this dialog did appear, I'm sure it did. My emulator has mucho latency due to the fact that my dev machine is a few years behind the times ( a good development practice btw.)

So, I did the following:

enable: system settings->Dev Settings and check Show cpu usage

this shows you all android processes running. You will see:

com.android.pinyin
just before the error.

google that error and hopefully come across this post.

go back into system settings->Language and input and change the default back to English.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem using the 4.0.3 WXGA800 emulator but could not disable the Chinese keyboard nor the Japanese IME keyboard since the check mark was greyed out (not blue). I was about to post a question when, by mistake, I clicked on the Default option, cycling through the different options until I came back to English (US). After that, fortunately the message stopped appearing.

I tried to post an image to show the check marks and the Default option, but as a new user was not able to.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as @Bobby, from Android +4 the check is unavailable. The solution was to disable the Chinese application. To make disable go to *"Settings" > "Apps"*, tap on **"ALL"** option in the action bar tab on the top, and at the end of the list you will be found the application, then tap in the item, and in the next screen make click in **"Force stop"** button and **"Disable"** button.

Answer (score 0):

This is my fix:

Settings > Language & Input > Keyboard and Input Methods > Default > English (US)

Changed default to another language and then back to English (US)

Message hasn't appeared for over 9000 seconds